# Getting Pesky Unable to load site preferences error

Tags: site-preferences

I am using EE 2.1.3 within the MSM. I have a number of other sites already setup on this MSM and not having any problems. I tried to add a new site and got the "Unable to load site preferences" message.

I verfied that config.php, database.php for the MSM are set to 777, cleared the cache for the site and still got the error. So, for this sites' index.php file I made $debug = 1; Now it is showing:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 303

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/techmark/webapps/_system_ee2msm/.system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 405

A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/EE_Config.php

Line Number: 176
```

Any idea how to fix this? Like I said earlier all of the other sites on this MSM are working correctly.

Here is the site: http://friendsunday.outreachcs.com/

Comment: To be clear... are you seeing this error on all your MSM sites or just this one?

Comment: Also, you are pretty far behind on your EE version... Is updating not possible?

Comment: Are you using a dynamic configuration for your database settings, such as Master Config? i.e. the database settings are set dynamically based upon the host name

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl - I am just seeing this on one site. Yes, we are far behind, but not time to update right now.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel - I don't think so.

Comment: This has me perplexed. An issue with the DB connection should take all sites offline.

Comment: As am I. I have deleted the site and started over only to get the same thing.

Comment: I think I am going to have to just wipe it all clean and try again.

Comment: I started over and even used a different short name for the site, but I still get these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to your PHP version being too new for the version of EE you are using.

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. [Link](https://www.php.net/mysql_escape_string)

Two options:

1. Lower your PHP version to 5.2
2. Upgrade to, at least, EE 2.3

Comment: But then why do all of the other sites on this MSM work?

Comment: did it not work?

Comment: I have about 5 five other sites that are working with this current setup. It is just this one that doesn't work

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: I am using 5.2.17

Comment: Ha! Okay. I'm with you now. That's weird. :)

Comment: Ha. I did check the application running for that particular site and it was running 5.4 while the others are running 5.2. I change to 5.2 and it is working now. Good catch! Thanks!

Now I just need to get around to upgrading EE to the current version. :)